# Adding unique identifier to an Insert statement

Tags: sql-server

I have this piece of code that I want to use to add an unique identifier to, but I cannot seem to get it to work correctly. Here is the code along with current output and desired output.

```
Begin
    DECLARE @StartDate  DATETIME,
            @EndDate    DATETIME,
            @MonthList as Varchar(50),
            @NewLeaseID as int,
            @LeaseID as int,
            @PropertyID as int, 
            @Amount as int,
            @ExpectedID as int

    SELECT   
        @StartDate = '20100501'        
        ,@EndDate   = '20100801'
        ,@leaseID = 6,
        @PropertyID = 12,
        @Amount = 600,
        @ExpectedID = (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(ExpectedPaymentID) + 1, 1) FROM Payments_ExpectedPayments)

    INSERT INTO Payments_ExpectedPayments(ExpectedPaymentID, Amount, PropertyID, LeaseID, Month)
       SELECT   
          @ExpectedID as ExpectedPaymentID,
          (x.number + 1) * @Amount as Amount, 
          @PropertyID as PropertyID, 
          @leaseID as Leaseid, 
          DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, x.number, @StartDate)) AS Month
       FROM    
          master.dbo.spt_values x
       WHERE   
          x.type = 'P'        
          AND x.number <= DATEDIFF(MONTH, @StartDate, @EndDate);
End
```

Output wanted:

```
ExpecedID   PropertyID    LeaseID   Month      Amount
1               12          13       Jan        600
2               12          13       Feb        1200
3               12          13       March      1800
4               12          13      April       2400
```

Output I'm currently getting:

```
ExpecedID   PropertyID    LeaseID   Month      Amount
1               12          13       Jan        600
1               12          13       Feb        1200
1               12          13       March      1800
1               12          13      April       2400
```

Comment: Why don't you use an [`IDENTITY` column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx)?

Comment: Please fix wording at bottom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Your table design needs to be fixed. You can use an identity column for `ExpectedId`. Just change the `CREATE TABLE` from `Expected int` to `Expected int identity(1,1)`.
2. You can use a `ROW_NUMBER()` on your `INSERT` like that: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY x.number) as ExpectedId`

Comment: Yes i was thinking of doing the row number but if some records where deleted then this would cause issues further down the line? I was also trying not to use the Identity  option and try and hard code it just for Future reference.

Comment: Why don't us use the identity? I don't understand the reason behind it.

Comment: It is mainly the code logic I thought would be useful to figure out, and could be useful somewhere else in my code.

Comment: Mh. Not really an answer. I'm developing sql code for more than a decade and normally an ID which is increments is the best instead of doing it on your own.

Comment: yeah okey thought it could come in handy for something other than an id but I have just used the identity and works fine

Answer (score 0):

This is failing because you set the @ExpectedID once, before your select statement, hence you get all the same values.

Try substituting the @ExpectedID parameter with the following line in your SELECT statement.

```
   (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(ExpectedPaymentID) + 1, 1) FROM Payments_ExpectedPayments) as ExpectedPaymentID
```

This will execute the select statement once per row, which I guess should work.

Comment: Yeah, i thought this may work also but it give back the same results as before. With all the IDs the same

Comment: Then I guess the auto increment identity column really is your best solution